# EF insert not using correct id for many-to-many xref table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, xunit

I am creating integration tests for a repository written around EF. During the setup of my test case, I am getting `SqlException`s about a FK being broken.

**Entities and entity table configuration**

Overall, the idea is that I have a `Contact` table whose entries can contain zero or more `ContactType`s. The types are fixed to an enumeration in code, but I have a table for them for referential integrity.

Here's some context around the entities in question:

```cs
public class Contact : EntityBase
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Address1 { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? PostalCode { get; set; }

    // Snip...all basic types

    public virtual IList<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; } = new List<ContactType>();
}

public class ContactType
{
    public ContactTypeEnum Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class ContactTypeXref
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public ContactTypeEnum ContactTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
}
```

Each entity has its own configuration, as well, to set up the tables in the database:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
{
    // Primary Key
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
           .HasColumnOrder(0);

    // Snip - map indices, audit columns, properties...
    

    // Many-to-Many Relationship Between Contacts and ContactTypes
    builder.HasMany(x => x.ContactTypes)
           .WithMany()
           .UsingEntity<ContactTypeXref>(
                ContactTypeXrefTableName,
                l => l.HasOne<ContactType>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactTypeId),
                r => r.HasOne<Contact>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactId),
                z =>
                {
                    // Setup payload property
                    z.Property(e => e.Created).HasDefaultValueSql(SqlServerSysDatetimeOffset);
                });
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContactType> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(TableName, x =>
            x.HasComment(
                "Table representation of ContactTypeEnum for referential integrity. Do not edit without matching change to Enum  in code."));

    builder.Property(x => x.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.HasData(
        new List<ContactType>
        {
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Carrier, Name = "Carrier" },
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Customer, Name = "Customer" },
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Shipper, Name = "Shipper" },
            new() { Id = ContactTypeEnum.Vendor, Name = "Vendor" },
        });
}
```

All the repository is doing within `AddAsync` is this:

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    await AppContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    await AppContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity;
}
```

**Problematic Integration Test**

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ListAsync_ShouldOnlyReturnCarrierContacts_WhenListContainsManyDifferentTypes()
{
    await ExecuteInAsyncTransaction(async () =>
    {
        // Arrange
        var carrierContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Carrier);
        var carrierContact = new Contact
        {
            Name = "Test Carrier Contact",
            Address1 = "456 Some Street",
            IsActive = true,
            ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
            {
                carrierContactType,
            },
        };
        await _contactRepository.AddAsync(carrierContact); // NOTE: This insert succeeds

        var vendorContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Vendor);

        var vendorContact = new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Test Vendor Contact",
            Address1 = "123 Another Street",
            IsActive = true,
            ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
            {
                vendorContactType,
            },
        };

        // NOTE: This insert fails
        await _contactRepository.AddAsync(vendorContact); 

        // Act
        var result = await _sut.ListAsync(new ListCarriersRequest());

        // Assert
        result.ShouldNotBeNull();
        result.Carriers.ShouldHaveSingleItem();
        result.Carriers.ShouldContain(x => x.Id == carrierContact.Id);
    });
}
```

The error I get is:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ContactTypeXrefs_Contacts_ContactId". The conflict occurred in database "VF_BillOfLading", table "dbo.Contacts", column 'Id'.

The SQL that ran is:

```
info: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.439 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[@p0='456 Some Street' (Size = 450), @p1=NULL (Size = 450), @p2=NULL (Size = 450), @p3=NULL (Size = 450), @p4='2023-09-20T14:40:49.3570311+00:00', @p5='testuser@volflex.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p6=NULL (Size = 4000), @p7=NULL (Size = 4000), @p8='True', @p9='False', @p10='False', @p11='2023-09-20T14:40:49.3570311+00:00', @p12='testuser@volflex.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p13='Test Carrier Contact' (Size = 450), @p14=NULL (Size = 4000), @p15=NULL (Size = 450), @p16=NULL (Size = 4000), @p17=NULL (Size = 450), @p18=NULL (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [Contacts] ([Address1], [Address2], [Address3], [City], [Created], [CreatedBy], [Email], [Fax], [IsActive], [IsCustomContact], [IsDeleted], [Modified], [ModifiedBy], [Name], [Phone], [PostalCode], [Scac], [State], [Url])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Version]
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18);
info: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.461 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p19='69', @p20='2'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ContactTypeXrefs] ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Created]
      VALUES (@p19, @p20);
info: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.482 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [c].[Id], [c].[Name]
      FROM [ContactTypes] AS [c]
      WHERE [c].[Id] = 0
info: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.492 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='123 Another Street' (Size = 450), @p1=NULL (Size = 450), @p2=NULL (Size = 450), @p3=NULL (Size = 450), @p4='2023-09-20T14:40:49.4864373+00:00', @p5='testuser@volflex.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p6=NULL (Size = 4000), @p7=NULL (Size = 4000), @p8='True', @p9='False', @p10='False', @p11='2023-09-20T14:40:49.4864373+00:00', @p12='testuser@volflex.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p13='Test Vendor Contact' (Size = 450), @p14=NULL (Size = 4000), @p15=NULL (Size = 450), @p16=NULL (Size = 4000), @p17=NULL (Size = 450), @p18=NULL (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [Contacts] ([Address1], [Address2], [Address3], [City], [Created], [CreatedBy], [Email], [Fax], [IsActive], [IsCustomContact], [IsDeleted], [Modified], [ModifiedBy], [Name], [Phone], [PostalCode], [Scac], [State], [Url])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Version]
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18);
info: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.494 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p19='-2147482646', @p20='0'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ContactTypeXrefs] ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Created]
      VALUES (@p19, @p20);
fail: 9/20/2023 09:40:49.512 CoreEventId.SaveChangesFailed[10000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update) 
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'BillOfLading.DataAccess.SqlServer.BillOfLadingDbContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement confl
```

What I think is peculiar is that the first record (Carrier Contact) inserts fine, along with its `ContactTypeXref` record:

```sql
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p19='69', @p20='2'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ContactTypeXrefs] ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Created]
      VALUES (@p19, @p20);
```

However, the second record (Vendor Contact) seems to be using some temporary `ContactId` (**@p19=-2147482646**) rather than the identity column value (I'd expect it to be 70):

```sql
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p19='-2147482646', @p20='0'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ContactTypeXrefs] ([ContactId], [ContactTypeId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], INSERTED.[Created]
      VALUES (@p19, @p20);
```

I feel like this is either something with how I set up my test, or something with an EF convention that I am not aware of.

Any thoughts on why doing multiple inserts within a test like this might cause problems?

#### Troubleshooting **(EDIT)**

Even this test, which only uses DbContext directly, fails with the same exception:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ListAsync_ShouldOnlyReturnCarrierContacts_WhenListContainsManyDifferentTypes()
{
    // Arrange
    var carrierContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Carrier);
    var carrierContact = new Contact
    {
        Name = "Test Carrier Contact",
        Address1 = "456 Some Street",
        IsActive = true,
        ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
        {
            carrierContactType,
        },
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(carrierContact);

    var vendorContactType = Context.ContactTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Id == ContactTypeEnum.Vendor);
    var vendorContact = new Contact()
    {
        Name = "Test Vendor Contact",
        Address1 = "123 Another Street",
        IsActive = true,
        ContactTypes = new List<ContactType>()
        {
            vendorContactType,
        },
    };
    Context.Contacts.Add(vendorContact);

    // NOTE: Context.Contacts.AddRange fails with same error

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No transaction, no repository, just direct calls on a `DbSet<Contact>` within a DbContext.

Comment: You're misusing EF Core and the `AddAsync` breaks the Unit-of-Work model completely. To fix this, remove the "repository" class and use DbContext the way the docs and tutorials show. As for what's going on: DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, tracking *all* pending changes. `DbContext.Add` doesn't add anything, it *attaches* a new object in the `Added` state *along with any other child objects*. When `SaveChanges` is called *all* pending changes (new, modified, deleted objects) are persisted to the database in the correct order. PK, FK values are fixed up automatically

Comment: The comments in the code show it explicitly tries to subvert EF Core - `stops the change tracker from knowing` ... `so we can use the same context` - but DbContext is the Unit-of-Work, it's *not* meant to be reused

Comment: By your description of what's going on, it doesn't explain the behavior. In `AddAsync` it is both adding the entity (`Contact` w/ its `ContactType`) and saving it, thereby completing the unit of work. A subsequent call to `AddAsync` should then execute a new unit of work. However, that doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect. I'm not going to rehash the UoW/Repo argument and my reasons for using a Repo.

Comment: It's not an argument. `that doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect` EF Core doesn't work that way. [The docs of AddAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-addasync(system-object-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) explain this is *not* meant for inserting into the database : `This method is async only to allow special value generators`. `Add` only attaches a new object in the `Added` state so it *doesn't* have to be async.

Comment: Why not try using DbContext the way the docs show? Create a new unit test, create a new context instance, add a couple of objects and check what happens. Use your database's profiler or tracer to see what's actually sent to the database and when. Or enable verbose logging in the DbContext, to see the actual commands in the log

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've removed my comment and added an edit at the bottom of my post doing what you suggested. Even with just a `DbContext`, it still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Here's a nice demo on where, within an integration test, you may want to clear state tracker: https://youtu.be/ExbioGgi-aA?si=3SrZOqGetX6kQ8W8&t=733. I see how he mentions using a second DbContext instance, which makes sense.